# JavaScript - Replace two characters with each other?

Tags: javascript

I have a string and I want to replace every capital 'I' with small 'i', and every small 'i' with a capital 'I'. As you can see if I do this in two stages it just converts it, then converts it back to how it was before. So how would I do it all at once?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function init() {
    text = document.getElementById('test');
    newtext = text.innerHTML.replace(/I/g, "i");
    newtext = newtext.replace(/i/g, "I");
    text.innerHTML = newtext;
}
</script>   
</head>

<body onload="init()">
<div id="test">
THIS IS SOME TEST 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
newtext = text.innerHTML.replace(/[iI]/g, function(l) {
  return l.toUpperCase() === l ?
    l.toLowerCase() : l.toUpperCase();
});
```

Comment: +1, and made a small edit so that it only works on `i` and `I`.

Comment: to me that sais 'if i is equal to I then return i' which dont make sense but owell it works lol

Comment: @AndyLobel, for every character that is either `i` or `I` the function will be called. It compares the letter to itself uppercase'd. So, for the letter `i`, `toUpperCase` will return `I` which is not `===` to `i`, meaning that the function will return the upper case version, and vice versa for the opposite.

Comment: @999 ah right i get it now, is there anything wrong with doing `return l == "i" ? "I" : "i";`